# Storing a users interaction in memory

Tags: ios

I have some social links within my app that users are rewarded for when they press on the buttons to follow my app/share the app online. I need to store their interaction with the buttons in memory so that they can't keep pressing the buttons to get rewards. Whats the best way to store this in memory? I could use `NSUserDefaults` but I know people can modify them.

Comment: If you want to avoid modification by the user you have to do it on your server.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Good idea, that's probably the best solution for me. If you put it as an answer I'll mark it correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create your own file structure for that and store results in binary format. You can even apply XOR or maybe AES encryption (that of course would be an overkill).

Just save to the documents directory in a binary blob. Here is the code I use

http://pastie.org/private/cgmkozukxurusjcjg5nfvq#39

It just takes an array of NSDictionary values and saves at 4 bytes per entry which are

1 byte - Star (0 or 1, has star or not) 1 byte - Locked (0 or 1, locked stage or not) 2 byte - Best (I just 2 bytes for this current project as max moves is 999)

then it just saves this as datX.bin.

You also, of course, can use a backend for that purpose, for example Parse.com or backnendless, or your own solution.